# Get a letter out of a word

Tags: python

```
a = ['cat','dog']

random.choice(a)
```

How can I choose a random word, and pull out a letter?
I've searched and experimented and whatnot but can't find an answer.
thanks.

I don't want a random letter,
for instances
I want it to choose a word, cat.
then I want someone to guess either c a or t.
Kind of like hangman

Comment: Do you want to pull a random letter or at a fixed index?

Comment: What's stopping you from printing a random letter from the random work you picked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First to pick the word, you use what you published.Then you can make a set from the word to get the set of letters it contains. And you can use it to check whether the input is part of the word and keep the remaining letters.
You can do:

```
chosen_word = random.choice(['cat', 'dog'])
letters_set = set(chosen_word)
while len(letters_set) > 0:
    letter = raw_input() #make controls on this.
    if letter in letters_set:
        letters_set.remove(letter)
        print "Good!"
        print ''.join(map(lambda c: c in letters_set and '_' or c, chosen_word))
    else:
        print "Bad Bad, try again!"
```

Hope it is useful.

Comment: Just to note, if the strings aren't of the same length this won't select a character completely randomly (e.g. consider `['a', '123456789']`)

Comment: but it will select with the same probability a word first and then the same probability for each letter in the word.

If you want each letter(of all strings together) to have the same probability then you should do sukhbir's solution.

Comment: You're welcome :) PD: You should accept the answer if that's what you were looking for

Comment: I see, sorry new to the site XD.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to choose a random character from the randomly selected word:

```
random.choice(random.choice(a))
```

Or, if you want the first letter (for example) of the randomly chosen word:

```
random.choice(a)[0]
```